# Why did Angelina ask if she's safe in Scream 3?

Tags: scream-3

In *Scream 3*, after the house blew up by Roman, Angelina asks Dewey, Gale and Jennifer "are we safe?".
Followed up by Dewey asking "safe from who?":

[image: Dewey asking "safe from who?"]

I didn't get this line by her.
Why ask if you know the killer is after you and especially after you got out of the house that blew up?

As I understand, Angelina was going to be a second Ghostface, but later on they changed it to 1 Ghostface.
Is that why? Did she try act innocent so they won't suspect her? (While filming the role as a killer at the time).